# Image of spatial distribution of particles in a plasma?

Tags: simulations, plasma-physics, debye-length

I am looking into the Debye length and to get an intuitive understanding of it I thought I would find an image showing a *simulation* of the (spatial) distribution of particles in a plasma i.e. a zoomed in snapshot of the plasma at a given time. After extensive searches I am yet to find anything. Does anyone know if such an image exists? If not why note?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into "particle-in-cell" (PIC) methods in plasma simulation.  There are several watys to describe plasmas, both in x(t) and v(t), neglecting particles correlations, or a fluid description. The PIC enables to represent the 6D phase space by sampling it using "particles". Your question is rather generic, while simulations usually look into some geometry or interaction with external fields.  Here's a [simple example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_XXxCTbUpI) of a PIC simulation...